# Class Amp non found

Tags: php, amphp

I'm new on amphp and i'd like to try this very simple code first.
I downloaded amphp with composer for windows and save all folder created inside my project folder.

```
composer require amphp/http-client
```

Then my code is:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . './autoload.php';

use Amp\Http\Client\HttpClientBuilder;
use Amp\Http\Client\HttpException;
use Amp\Http\Client\Request;
use Amp\Http\Client\Response;
use Amp\Loop;

$stringa = 'http://www.google.it/';

$request = new Request($stringa, "GET");
$location = $request->getHeader("Location");

var_dump($location);
```

But I get always 'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Amp\Http\Client\Request' not found'

Any suggest?

I use wamp local server with php 7.0

Also ,after, I need to `yield` all the code...

Comment: If you solved this issue, it'd be great if you could share the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things that look for:

- Did the `autoload.php` get included correctly?

  - I see there is an unnecessary `.` before `/autoload.php`.
- Did you use the correct class name with the correct namespace?
- Did you run `composer require amphp/http-client` so that the libraries will be installed?
- Do the library's files exist inside the `vendor/amphp/http-client` directory?
- If you're on Windows, use `\` in the `require` statement.

Apart from these, I can't think of why the library won't load. I hope this helps.